# Send key press to popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a button on the main page that I want to, onclick send a key press to the popup (in this case the key I want to send is enter). Here is my code:

```
<body>
<script>
var w = screen.width - 100
var diep = window.open("http://diep.io/", "", "resizable=yes,left=100,width=" + w + ",height=" + screen.height)
</script>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
diep.close()
}
</script>
<button onclick="diep.focus(); sendENTER()">Send Enter</button><br>

<script>
function sendENTER(){
//Code here to send the ENTER key press to diep.io in the popup
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is rest of the code?

Comment: not possible, write your own game

Comment: @SandeepNayak there is no other code

Answer (score 0):

try to consider your solution this way using event listener:

```
<button id="myBtn">Send Enter</button><br>

<script>
  var myButton = document.getElementById('myBtn');

  myButton.addEventListener('click', sendENTER);

  function sendENTER(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 /* 13 stands for ENTER */) {
      // do something
    }

    diep.focus();
  }
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work because I have the button on the main page. I need the button to send a key press to the popup. I can't do any code in the popup either because it is an already existing site in it.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are trying to interact with **diep.io** from your *hacky* local webpage.

But due some security policies it is clearly not possible to interact with another webpage.
Even if you use iframes or other techniques.

This are some policies that stop you from doing that:

- Same-Origin Policy
- Cross-Origin Policy
- Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Since your Web-browser handler this policies you can disable some of them with about:config fags but it would be hard to interact anyways.

Since you are obviously not creating any public webpage,
you can create a **browser-add-on** and **inject** javascript code from an **content script**.